# Update data on a web portal based on the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, webautomation

What I am trying to Do : Update the metadata of a record on web portal based data in excel sheet

So far I have been able to get to login in to the page:

```
 Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    set i - New internetexplorer
    i.Visible = True
    i.Navigate ("URL")
    Do While i.ReadyState <> READY_COMPLETE Loop
    Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTML.Document
    Set idoc = i.Document
    idoc.all.login.Value = "ID"
    idoc.all.pass.Value = "password"
    idoc.getelementbyid("login_button").Click
```

When I try to `getelementbyID` or tag for the next drop down menu, `idoc.doc.getelementbyid("order").Click` this doesn't work..
I am new to this any guidence would be really helpful. I am NOT looking for free Codes.. just point me in the right direction and I will research

**Update**
 So I eliminated the login issue, using the SSO link now, updated code and this part works :

```
Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 
set i - New internetexplorer 
i.Visible = True 
i.Navigate ("URL") 
Do While i.ReadyState <> READY_COMPLETE 
Loop 
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTML.Document 
Set doc = i.Document 
Dim ele As Mshtml.ihtmlelement 
Dim eles As mshtml.ihtmlelementcollection 
Doc.getelementsbytagname("input").item("order").value = _
            worksheet("sheet1").range("a1").value
```

.. NOT Working : When I call search button by tag name and .click

Comment: Are `set i - New internetexplorer` (should be `=` instead) and `Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTML.Document` (should be `MSHTML.HTMLDocument`) just typos in the question rather than issues in your actual code?

Comment: What is `idoc.doc` ?  `idoc` is already a document object.  Did you reset `idoc` after the new page load following login?  Otherwise `idoc` is still pointing at the login page.

Comment: @barrowc ya thats just typos as I cant copy paste the code from my VM so i had to write it.

Comment: @TimWilliams so After the login in page, to go in further to "Browse Orders" page , I will have to define "orders" page and then call out elements from that ??

Comment: There are many related questions here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+automate+IE   I would start be reviewing some of those for guidance. You have to wait for the login process to complete, and then get a reference to the next page so you can work with it.

Comment: So I eliminated the login issue, using the SSO link now, updated code and this part works :   Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    set i - New internetexplorer
    i.Visible = True
    i.Navigate ("URL")
    Do While i.ReadyState <> READY_COMPLETE Loop
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTML.Document
    Set doc = i.Document
Dim ele As Mshtml.ihtmlelement   Dim eles As mshtml.ihtmlelementcollection  Doc.getelementsbytagname("input").item("order").value=worksheet("sheet1").range("a1").value .. NOT Working : When I call search button by tag name and .click

Comment: Please update your question if you have code or other info to add - we can't really read code posted in comments.  Also "not working" is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code.